# HTML Load Elements on Click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a new website, a blog and I need to reduce load time by only loading elements when the user clicks a button. I post pictures (with captions) like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Caption</p>
       </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
       <td>
           <img src="path">
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want only 10 pictures to appear at a time and a button at the bottom of the page to load 10 more. I can't use show/hide or visibility becuase the images will still be downloaded along with the page, just not displayed. I've only been web designing for a little over a year so I don't know that much about JS and JQuery.

Its probably going to be fixed in the future but if you want to see it in its current state is at http://thedrawingblog.com in the Gallery/Posts section.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to use the `hidden` attribute and a `data-*` attribute.

```
<img id="img-to-show" hidden data-src="path/to/image.jpg" />
<button id="show-img-btn">Show image</button>
```

When you want to show the images:

```
document.getElementById('show-img-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var image = document.getElementById('img-to-show');
    image.removeAttribute('hidden');
    image.src = image.dataset.src;
});
```

---

I'm not sure exactly what structure you're using for multiple images, but hopefully this makes enough sense that you can transform it to your needs:

Example html:

```
<div id="images">
    <div hidden>
        <div>Caption</div>
        <img data-src="path/to/image.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div hidden>
        <div>Caption 2</div>
        <img data-src="path/to/image2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div hidden>
        <div>Caption 3</div>
        <img data-src="path/to/image3.jpg" />
    </div>
    ...
</div> 
<button id="show-img-btn">Show image</button>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('show-img-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){

    // get the hidden divs
    var imageDivs = document.getElementById('images').querySelectorAll('[hidden]');

    // convert to array, and slice out the first 10.
    var imageDivsArray = [].slice.call(imageDivs,0,10);

    // loop through the divs, showing each one,
    // and setting the src of the child <img>
    imageDivsArray.forEach(function(el,idx,arr) {
        // remove the `hidden` attribute
        el.removeAttribute('hidden');

        // grab the child image
        var img = el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

        // set the src
        img.src = img.dataset.src;
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jsdn46Lk/

There are some definite optimizations that could be made here, but unless you're loading a seriously large amount of images, you should be fine.

Comment: sure, this works for hiding the images and shortening load time, but it still has problems. The caption is not hidden and to apply it to many images and captions? well then you'd need multiple ID's all different from each other. Is there a way to do this by using classes?

Comment: I've added some example code and a jsfiddle to my answer for multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the images to be loaded they'll have to be loaded from elsewhere. There's two basic options for this, lets take the worst one first.

**The 1990's Approach**

```
// Create an array of images
var images = ['images/img1.jpg', 'images/img2.jpg', 'images/img3.jpg']

// Where are we in the image list?
var counter = 0

// Listen for button click
$('.more-images').click(function() {

    // Make sure we don't try to load more images than there are by
    // reducing the limit
    if(counter + 10 > images.length) {
        var limit = images.length
    } else {
        var limit = counter + 10
    }

    // Add a number of images with jQuery, in this case 10.
    for(counter; counter<limit; counter++) {
        $('.images-container').append('<img src="' + images[counter] + '">')
    }
})
```

**The 2000's Approach**

I won't bother doing another sample code as it's pretty much the same as before, except there will be an [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request after the click.

*Disclaimer: Untested code, tell me if it's wrong please.*

Comment: The for loop should have `;`, not `,`

Comment: Nice, just don't forget to load the jQuery library

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an similar [DEMO](http://www.phpmysqlcode.com/jquery-load-more-data-on-click-using-php-and-ajax-from-database/) in php.
And here you have anotherone without php, this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nFd7C/) uses html, js, css.
I hope it will hellp you...

html code:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <li>Thirteen</li>
    <li>Fourteen</li>
    <li>Fifteen</li>
    <li>Sixteen</li>
    <li>Seventeen</li>
    <li>Eighteen</li>
    <li>Nineteen</li>
    <li>Twenty one</li>
    <li>Twenty two</li>
    <li>Twenty three</li>
    <li>Twenty four</li>
    <li>Twenty five</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

css code:

```
#myList li{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

and js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Load the first 3 list items from another HTML file
    //$('#myList').load('externalList.html li:lt(3)');
    $('#myList li:lt(3)').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        $('#myList li:lt(10)').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        $('#myList li').not(':lt(3)').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: this would work, yes, but it doesnt apply how i want it to. First, it doesn't shorten the page load time because the images will still be downloaded along with the page, just hidden from the users view. The point of my problem is to retreive the elements when the user clicks a button, not to simply change how the page looks.